# Temporary file problem

Tags: interface

I had a problem, I changed the path for temporary files to another disk in the blender settings, but it still saves them to disk C, I even changed the location of temporary files in windows, and blender still saves them to disk C

Comment: Hello and welcome. where did u change the path?

Comment: Did you change the path via Edit > Preferences > File Paths > Data in Blender and if so did you then save your settings via the three-bar icon on the bottom-left corner of that dialog?

Comment: Yes, I did and it didn't work